# I am getting error while replacing url in orginal code python,selenium,re

Tags: python, r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-re

i used code in this question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241842/webscraping-with-selenium-a-course-downloader-and-sorter/248712#248712

i replaced  url in that code to my url
when i compile get an error shown below

line 66, in 
current_file_name = re.search(r'https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev//0://Courses//Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag//TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/.+/(.+)', download_path, re.DOTALL).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

i figured i that  in code i used websiteaddress
in "current_file_name" has some extra letters like backward slash
i have no idea about it
i tried to do like same by adding some backward slash but no fix

but when i run orginal code it works fine
when i use it in my desired site it end up with error that mentioned above

below is my edited code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
import re

path = r'https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev/0:/Courses/Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag/TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/'

# For changing the download location for this browser temporarily
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\shanid\Desktop\test", "safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

# Acquire the Course Link and Get all the directories
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get(r"https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev/0:/Courses/Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag/TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/")
time.sleep(2)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")

# loop for as many directories there are
for i in range(0, len(elements)):
    print("deft")

    # At each directory, it refreshes the page to update the webelements in the list, and returns the current directory that is being worked on
    browser.get(path)
    time.sleep(2)
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
    element = elements[i]

    # checks if the folder for the directory already exists
    current_directory_name = element.text[11:].strip(" .")
    current_folder_path = "C:\\Users\\shanid\\Desktop\\test\\" + current_directory_name
    if os.path.exists(current_folder_path):
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(current_folder_path)

    # Formatting what has been downloaded and sorted, and
    print(current_directory_name, "------------------------------", sep="\n")

    # moves on to the directory to get the page with the files
    element.click()

    # pausing for a few secs for the page to load, and running the same mechanism to get each file using the same method used in directory
    time.sleep(3)
    files = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
    for j in range(len(files)):
        files = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
        _file = files[j]
    # constants for some if statements
        download = True
        move = True
        current_file_name = _file.text[17:].strip()

    # If file exists, then pass over it, and don't do anything, and moveon to next file
        if os.path.exists(current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name):
            pass

    # If it doesnt exist, then depending on its extension, do specific actions with it
        else:
            # Downloads the mp4 files by clicking on it, and finding the input tag which contains the download link for vid in its value attribute
            if ".mp4" in current_file_name:
                _file.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                download_path = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input").get_attribute("value")
                current_file_name = re.search(r'https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev//0://Courses//Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag//TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/.+/(.+)', download_path, re.DOTALL).group(1)
                # Checks if file exists again, incase the filename is different then the predicted filename orderly generated.
                if os.path.exists(current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name):
                    move = False
                    download = False
                # returns to the previous page with the files
                browser.back()

            # self explanatory
            elif ".html" in current_file_name:
                download_path = path + current_directory_name + "/" + current_file_name
                if os.path.exists(current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name):
                    move = False
                    download = False

            else:
            # acquires the download location by going to the parent tag which is an a tag containing the link for html in its 'href' attribute
                download_path = _file.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href').replace(r"%5E", "^")
                current_file_name = re.search(r'https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev/0:/Courses/Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag/TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/.+/(.+)', download_path, re.DOTALL).group(1).replace("%20", " ")

            time.sleep(2)
            current_file_path = "C:\\Users\\shanid\\Desktop\\test\\" + current_file_name
            # responsible for downloading it using a path, get allows downloading, by source links
            if download:
                browser.get(download_path)

                # while the file doesn't exist/ it hasn't been downloaded yet, do nothing
                while True:
                    if os.path.exists(current_file_path):
                        break
                time.sleep(1)

            # moves the file from the download spot to its own folder
            if move:
                shutil.move(current_file_path, current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name)
        print(current_file_name)

    # formatter
    print("------------------------------", "", sep="\n")
    time.sleep(3)
```

orginal code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
import re

path = r'https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]%20Udemy%20-%20Master%20the%20Coding%20Interview%20Data%20Structures%20+%20Algorithms/'

# For changing the download location for this browser temporarily
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": r"E:\Utilities_and_Apps\Python\MY PROJECTS\Test data\Downloads", "safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

# Acquire the Course Link and Get all the directories
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get(r"https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]%20Udemy%20-%20Master%20the%20Coding%20Interview%20Data%20Structures%20+%20Algorithms/")
time.sleep(2)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")

# loop for as many directories there are
for i in range(0, len(elements)):

    # At each directory, it refreshes the page to update the webelements in the list, and returns the current directory that is being worked on
    browser.get(path)
    time.sleep(2)
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
    element = elements[i]

    # checks if the folder for the directory already exists
    current_directory_name = element.text[11:].strip(" .")
    current_folder_path = "E:\\Utilities_and_Apps\\Python\\MY PROJECTS\\Test data\Downloads\\" + current_directory_name
    if os.path.exists(current_folder_path):
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(current_folder_path)

    # Formatting what has been downloaded and sorted, and 
    print(current_directory_name, "------------------------------", sep="\n")

    # moves on to the directory to get the page with the files
    element.click()

    # pausing for a few secs for the page to load, and running the same mechanism to get each file using the same method used in directory 
    time.sleep(3)
    files = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
    for j in range(len(files)):
        files = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
        _file = files[j]
    # constants for some if statements
        download = True
        move = True
        current_file_name = _file.text[17:].strip()

    # If file exists, then pass over it, and don't do anything, and moveon to next file
        if os.path.exists(current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name):
            pass

    # If it doesnt exist, then depending on its extension, do specific actions with it 
        else:
            # Downloads the mp4 files by clicking on it, and finding the input tag which contains the download link for vid in its value attribute
            if ".mp4" in current_file_name:
                _file.click()
                time.sleep(2)  
                download_path = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input").get_attribute("value")
                current_file_name = re.search(r'https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/\[coursevania.com\]%20Udemy%20-%20Master%20the%20Coding%20Interview%20Data%20Structures%20\+%20Algorithms/.+/(.+)', download_path, re.DOTALL).group(1)
                # Checks if file exists again, incase the filename is different then the predicted filename orderly generated.
                if os.path.exists(current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name):
                    move = False
                    download = False
                # returns to the previous page with the files
                browser.back()

            # self explanatory
            elif ".html" in current_file_name:
                download_path = path + current_directory_name + "/" + current_file_name
                if os.path.exists(current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name):
                    move = False
                    download = False

            else:
            # acquires the download location by going to the parent tag which is an a tag containing the link for html in its 'href' attribute
                download_path = _file.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href').replace(r"%5E", "^")
                current_file_name = re.search(r'https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/\[coursevania.com\]%20Udemy%20-%20Master%20the%20Coding%20Interview%20Data%20Structures%20\+%20Algorithms/.+/(.+)', download_path, re.DOTALL).group(1).replace("%20", " ")

            time.sleep(2)
            current_file_path = "E:\\Utilities_and_Apps\\Python\\MY PROJECTS\\Test data\Downloads\\" + current_file_name
            # responsible for downloading it using a path, get allows downloading, by source links
            if download:
                browser.get(download_path)

                # while the file doesn't exist/ it hasn't been downloaded yet, do nothing
                while True:
                    if os.path.exists(current_file_path):
                        break
                time.sleep(1)

            # moves the file from the download spot to its own folder
            if move:
                shutil.move(current_file_path, current_folder_path + "\\" + current_file_name)
        print(current_file_name)

    # formatter
    print("------------------------------", "", sep="\n")
    time.sleep(3)
```

this code works fine

but not working when i change the website to https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev/0:/Courses/Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag/TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/

the site i  used is clone of orginal site

i have no idea why getting  error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the CSS selector for input box on below page.
https://player.hdflixcore.workers.dev/0:/Courses/Account%20Cracking%20--MrSihag/TN%20Cracking%20Course%20--MrSihag/01%20Course%20Introduction/1%20Course%20Introduction.mp4?a=view

There are 2 inputs boxes on the page, so you have to write CSS path as`"#content > div > div:nth-child(6) > input"`.

Code with issue.

```
download_path = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input").get_attribute("value")
```

To be replaced with.

```
download_path = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#content > div > div:nth-child(6) > input").get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: sir i changed code as you mentioned  it worked thankyou for your help  may god bless you  i cannot upvote because i am new user any way thanks a lot